# Linq - Join 2 tables and Select all columns VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to use linq to inner join two DataTables and return a result that has all the columns from both the DataTables

```
Dim qryResult = (From qryAllItemsAllFields In dtAllItemsAllFields
                 Join qryGetAttributes In dtGetAttributes On qryGetAttributes.Field(Of String)("ITNBR") Equals qryAllItemsAllFields.Field(Of String)("itemnum")
                Select New With {qryGetAttributes, qryAllItemsAllFields}).ToList()
```

The result of this query never returns any results (I checked and the result of this join should return results). I'm pretty new to linq, so any guidance would be much appreciated.

**Update**: I kept poking around and found that the item count of the list produced by the code is 6000 (so it is producing results), but when I try to bind the list to a GridView it throws an error saying: *The data source for GridView with id 'gvTest' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your data source has content.*

Comment: Try reversing the items on either side of the "Equals".  I believe order is important.

Comment: Ignore what I said above.  That doesn't matter.  But how are you using qryResult.  It will be an collection of object with two properies, each of which is a DataRow.  GridView is expecting just a collections of DataRows.

Comment: I am simply trying to use  qryResult as the datasource for the gridview, but I'm guessing that's not the way to go about it

Comment: Try setting the datasource to `qryResult.qryGetAttributes` and see it it works. (it'll only give you half of what you are looking for, but it's a starting point)

Comment: Ok, referencing the element directly does bind the gridview correctly, so I may be able to do something with that

Answer (score 0):

Using some fairly Reflection heavy code, it is possible to convert anonymous objects to `Dictionary`s and then combine them, or convert them to `ExpandoObject` and combine them. This prevents dealing with a large number of fields and provides something like the SQL `*` wildcard that LINQ is missing, but I don't know that I would recommend it for production.

```
Dim qryResult = (From qryAllItemsAllFields In dtAllItemsAllFields
                 Join qryGetAttributes In dtGetAttributes On qryGetAttributes.Field(Of String)("ITNBR") Equals qryAllItemsAllFields.Field(Of String)("itemnum")
                Select qryGetAttributes.ToExpando().AddAnon(qryAllItemsAllFields)).ToList()
```

My extensions are written in C# but the result from above is an `ExpandoObject` with all the fields from both source objects flattened out, which would probably be acceptable to a `GridView`.